Showing irreducibility of representations and modules
Let $\rho:S_5 \rightarrow GL_5(\mathbb{C})$ be the representation of the permutation matrix $(e_{\sigma(1)},...,e_{\sigma(5)})$. I am stuck on the following:

Why is $U= \{a_1e_1+...+a_5e_5|a_1+...+a_5=0\}$ an irreducible module?
Why is $\rho|_{A_5}:A_5 \rightarrow GL(U)$ irreducible?

My professor gave this as an example but without proving the above statements. For the second part, I guess it comes down to showing that the character $\chi$ of this representation satisfies $\langle \chi, \chi \rangle=\frac{1}{|A_5|}\sum_{\sigma \in A_5} \chi(\sigma)\overline{\chi(\sigma)}=1$, but I am stuck on the specifics on how to show this. Do I somehow need to use the first property?

Character theory is overkill here, you can show directly that it's irreducible. Pick any nonzero vector and start acting on it and try to show you can get the whole thing. Start with the vector $(1, -1, 0, 0, 0)$ for concreteness but you should see a general argument if you keep playing around with it.
